# Webform mail sending is successful but message says otherwise

Tags: 7, webforms, external-scripts

I have this webform for contact. The site uses [phpmailer 7.x-3.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer) and library 5.2.9.

When the webform is submitted, I get the error :

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists

and dblog says

> Sender: info@example.com Recipient:

but I get the message anyway. How come does this happen?

Comment: Quick idea - check if the form settings are correct.

Comment: Yeah they are. Besides, I get that error and yet the e-mail is sent.